# .net core 3 Problem while registering ApplicationDbContext for dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

when i register other services it work like `services.AddSingleton<GeneratingData, GeneratingData>()` but when i add `services.AddSingleton<ApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();` it does work
[this error shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFCwe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgHaL.png)
this is the code i write in startup file
[adding ApplicationDbContext for dependency injection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfvrZ.png)

Comment: Screenshots of code or error messages aren't accepted here. Please edit the code and messages into your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read the [tour] and [ask]. Start by reading the error message and researching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to inject a `scoped` service (`ApplicationDbContext`) in a `singleton`, that is not allowed since it will basically be captured as a `singleton`. If you want to use the DbContext, you will need to register the class that are going to use it as `Scoped` or `Transient` instead of `Singleton`

Comment: Thank you it worked. bye the way how to know which service scoped or singleton?